# Uses of double が, or が + は, in the same sentence, in Japanese

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-は, particle-が

This sentence:

> もう少しディスプレイが大きいのはありませんか。

is supposed to mean:

> Do you have one with a slightly larger display?

However, I don't understand why もう少し doesn't go attached to 大きい, since the former is modifying the latter.

However, I imagine that saying もう少し大きいディスプレイのはありませんか would mean: "Do you have a slightly smaller display?"

I don't understand how the position of the adjetives plus that extra が achieves the mentioned meaning.

Comment: Note that the firstィin ディスプレイ should be a small one. I have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> もう少しディスプレイが大きいのはありませんか。
> Don't you have one with a slightly larger display?

Word order is quite flexible in Japanese. You could certainly move もう少し to be in front of 大きい to get ディスプレイがもう少し大きいのはありませんか, and it would not change the meaning.

もう少し大きいディスプレイのはありませんか is ungrammatical. ディスプレイ is already a noun so the の is redundant. If you remove の then you have something grammatical but you are asking a different question: "Don't you have a larger display". You would be asking for the display rather than the object that has a display (TV?).

> However, I imagine that saying もう少し大きいディスプレイのはありませんか would mean: "Do you have a slightly smaller display?"

I can't understand why you would think this. It suggests that maybe there is something else about the sentence structure that is tripping you up. Perhaps you could explain further.
I also don't know what you mean by the 'extra が'. There is only one が in the sentence.

**Edit to address comments**

To reiterate, もう少し大きいディスプレイのはありませんか is not grammatical, and it cannot mean "Do you have a slightly smaller display?" To ask for a smaller display you would take your original sentence and replace 大きい with 小さい.

Now what about the が? I hope you will agree that ディスプレイが大きい means "the display is big" and that the が is an important part of this sentence and marks the subject of the sentence.

Now let us consider ディスプレイが大きいテレビ (A TV where the display is big). This is a **relative clause**. If you are not familiar with this concept then look it up (I think this concept may be the root cause of your confusion). Basically a noun can be described by the clause that precedes it. You see テレビ and ask "what kind of TV". The answer is "a TV **where** ディスプレイが大きい" i.e. "A TV **where** the display is big. 'where', 'whose' etc 'in which' and so on, do not have equivalent words in Japanese. They are handled by this relative clause concept.

Finally ディスプレイが大きいの works the same way as ディスプレイが大きいテレビ but instead of テレビ we have a special noun, の, that means "one", i.e. "the one where the display is big".

Comment: By 'extra ga' I mean that my last sentence only uses 'ha', not like there first one that uses both 'ha' and 'ga'.

Comment: Okay. It seems like you have some fundamental problems with the grammar of the sentence. I will try to explain in more detail.

Comment: With regards to why I misunderstood the last sentence, I mean that for instance 'ookii no ha desu' means 'a bigger one', the 'no' refers to the bigger object. However, as you say, disupurei is a noun, and it is followed by the same 'no ha' structure mentioned above, that confuses me. I don't find anything expressing that the display is part of the object about which the question is asked.